# how can I get the *.crt and *.key from *.cer file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, certificate-authority

My client's company internal CA provided a *.cer file.
I already installed this file in the our server using MMC but I also need to add the .crt and .key files to the apache configuration.

How can I get the .crt and .key file from the .cer file that the CA issued?

Comment: The file extensions aren't really meaningful, it's the contents that matter. What's in the .cer file?

Comment: Doesn't matter, if that's the way that you get the private key then you should not trust it anymore. Ask DigiNotar - oh, no, they went bankrupt for some reason or other :P

Comment: The private key isn't in the certificate. Your company CA would (or at least should) only have provided that certificate file in response to a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) issued to them by you, at which point you already had the private key file. If their process is different, it's wrong, as @MaartenBodewes says.

Answer (score 1):

A `.cer` file is a certificate file. It contains a certificate either in DER format (binary) or PEM format (the same DER formatted binary, base 64 encoded, with header and footer). Usually there is no difference between `.cer` and `.crt`: they represent the same (X.509v3) certificate.

Generally *you* create the key pair, then a certificate request which you send to the CA. You get back a certificate *for that particular key pair* that you created and - hopefully - stored somewhere secure. If you didn't store the private key securely you're out of luck and you should start over again.